# Htaccess: showing same page on second domain with simplified url structure

Tags: .htaccess, mirroring, multiple-domains

This should be easy, but it really isn't.

I want to accomplish this:

- http://**finaldomain.com**/PAGENAME is the url I would like
  to use.
- http://**subdomain.generaldomain**.com/index.php?/static-parameter/PAGENAME is what the server needs to render the page

A mirroring with htaccess is what I am looking for. Not a redirect.
Can this be done?

Thanks in advance,
Diederik

Answer (score 0):

Try this `.htaccess` in your document root.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?finaldomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.generaldomain.com/index.php?/static-parameter/$1 [L]
```

This would redirect

```
http://www.finaldomain.com/file.php => to =>
http://subdomain.generaldomain.com/index.php?/static-parameter/file.php

http://finaldomain.com/subfolder/file.php => to =>
http://subdomain.generaldomain.com/index.php?/static-parameter/subfolder/file.php
```